# Validating CC while using Membrr and Stripe

Tags: membrr

When a new user is created on my site, its suppose to bill the account a recurring fee of $8 but for some reason an account can be created without entering any Credit Card information at all.  Heres a [picture of the plans](http://d.pr/1P3b) from the Membrr Module.

The Transaction doesnt even show up in Stripe which I'm not sure if its suppose to in test mode, but just in case it is I thought I would mention that. The API Keys I used were the Test Secret Key, and Live Secret Key if that helps any

How can I stop the user from getting pass the registration page if they enter incorrect or no Credit Card Information?

**Edit after nonprofit_tech's reply:**

I'm trying to allow users that are logged into the "members" member group to have access to specific content on the website.  On the registration page, the user is asked to add in their Billing Information and Login Details.  They are given a 30 day free trial and the credit card would be charged when the trial period ends.

[Here is my form](http://d.pr/nYTD)

After registration the user is moved to the group "members" and on expiration they are moved to "expired members"

So with the way the registration process is here, would it be possible to validate the Billing Information at this point, or is the only option after the 30 days when the card is to be charged?

In OpenGateway, I have stripe set up as the only Gateway.

**Stripe Details In Open Gateway:**

- Enable This gateway?: Enabled
- Enabled Mode: Live Mode
- Test API Key: sk_test_xxxxxxx
- Live API Key: sk_live_xxxxxxx
- Accept Visa: Yes
- Accept MasterCard: Yes
- Accept Discover: Yes
- Accept American Express: Yes

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing a fair amount of detail, but I'm going to make some assumptions. The first assumption is that you are set-up in test mode. The second is that you haven't created a default **'no privilege'** member account.

From what I can see from the [Membrr Docs](http://www.membrr.com/docs/plans) is that Membrr doesn't so much interfere with the standard ExpressionEngine registration process, as opposed to allowing you to charge. The following information from the Membrr Docs is what I'm looking at:

> Member Group after Purchase - (Optional) What member group should the
>   user be moved to when they are a subscriber to this plan?

and

> Member Group after Expiration - (Optional) What member group should
>   the user be moved to after their subscription to this plan expires?

I could be wrong, but basically new registration should go into a membership level with no privileges, say just 'members'. Then, **Membrr** will handle transferring them to a member_group with privileges after payment has been processed, so they could be moved from say 'members' to 'monthly', 'yearly', or 'fitness'.

You'd then use the membership level to restrict or provide access to various content on the site.

Your test set-up of Stripe should log your test transactions. That's the purpose, to see if the gateway is working for you. So I'd assume there's something wrong with your set-up there, as well.

But more detail about, what you want to do, maybe some sample code of how you set-up registration, etc. would be good.

Comment: in OpenGateway I have Stripe set to Live, but when logged into Stripe its on test mode, I don't have a "no privilege" but after purchase members are moved to the "members" group, and on expiration they are moved to "expired members". I'll create a no privilege group but what about the 30 day free trial period? How do I allow access to that content if users will t be moved to "members" until after the card is processed? I'll start adding more detail to the main post now

Comment: The `no privileges` group could be the `free trial` group. I don't really know much about your set-up. But basically, you would define the member groups to match your set-up. So if anyone who registers gets a free trial, they'd go into that group first, then be moved into the appropriate pay group, if they paid. How much access you provide trial members is up to you, and Membrr should handle expiration of trial period.

Comment: the main issue I'm having now is getting validation errors to appear without a free trial. creating new transactions from OpenGateway -> work fine, the transactions that should work pass to stripes dashboard and the ones that dont report the correct errors.. but when its from my form on my site, it does not give an error when the user is suppose to be charged instantly.. it just creates the account while bypassing the error that should be displayed

Comment: I would assume Stripe isn't properly configured on your site. I'm not certain if that would be a Membrr issue or a Stripe issue, but I'd open a support ticket with one of them. Or one thing I do, is if they've provided examples. I start with the examples exactly as they are, with just changing channel names or member groups. Test. If they work, then I make just one or two modifications at a time, then test again. This way you know, where the error was introduced and can troubleshoot from there.